# Update struts 2 autocompleter from another autocompleter

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, struts2, foreign-keys

I'm using struts+spring+hibernate.

On my .jsp page, I have two autocompleter drop down menus.  Each one returns a list of VOs from their specific table in the database, which is then used to call a search action that searches from another table.  Menu A links to table A, and menu B links to table B, and they are used to search in table C.  However, table B has a foreign key that links it to table A  Table C has a foreign key that links it to table B.

I would like it to be that when the user picks an option from menu A, menu B is updated so it only includes options that contain the proper foreign key.  The user then can pick something specific from menu B and have the action search table C only for rows containing the proper foreign key.  If the user does not touch table B, then the action will search for all rows in table C containing all foreign keys from Table B that match the one chosen in table A.

I hope this is understandable and let me know if I need to clarify.  I've been googling for some time and it might be a simple solution but I can't find anything.  Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use ajax, easiest is the struts2-json-plugin, then you would create an action to render the initial form, an action which when provided with a collection of values will return a json object containing the values which your ajax call will put into column B, and finally an action which when provided with your selections in Column B will return the result, again using ajax + struts2-json-plugin if on the the same page or if it will render on a different page the action will use the default dispatcher result.

Comment: How do I get the json object into my ajax call for Column B?

Comment: Start with an action capable of returning a block of jason. Then pose a strictly javascript/jquery questions showing your html and the json object and someone will be able to concretely answer that. jQuery/javascript questions are SO are answered remarkably quickly (at least concrete ones).

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the href of the widget of your second autocompleter to the old json query + an extraparmeter using

```
jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(widget,options_auto_iban_widget);
```

I just post an example on : [How to reload the struts2-jquery autocompleter X with value selected from another struts2-jquery autocompleter Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608149/how-to-reload-the-struts2-jquery-autocompleter-x-with-value-selected-from-anothe/19301212#19301212)