# How to reload the struts2-jquery autocompleter X with value selected from another struts2-jquery autocompleter Y

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, struts, struts2-jquery

I have the two strut2 Jquery autocompleter box called x,y in my jsp page. If i change x , then automatically y also should change according to selected value of x.In struts dojo tags i used listen topics to reload . But strut2 jquery not able to reload .

my code

```
             <sj:autocompleter
                id="mapNameList"
                name="map_name"
                list="%{mapNameList}"
                selectBox="true"
                selectBoxIcon="true"
                onChangeTopics="autocompleteChange"
                onFocusTopics="autocompleteFocus"
                onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect"
                />
        <label for="map_type">MapType: </label>
            <sj:autocompleter
                id="mapTypeList"
                name="map_type"
                list="%{mapTypeList}"
                selectBox="true"
                selectBoxIcon="true"
                onChangeTopics="autocompleteChange"
                onFocusTopics="autocompleteFocus"
                onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer json autocompleter to list one you can do :

define the onSelectTopics of the first on to a specific value like

```
onSelectTopics="/mapNameListChange"
```

define for the second

```
listenTopics="/mapNameListChange"
```

create a function like :

```
$.subscribe("/mapNameListChange",function(event, data){
            //clear the children autocompleters
            jQuery('#mapTypeList').val("");
            jQuery('#mapTypeList_widget').val("");
            var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
            if (ui.item && ui.item.value.length > 0) {
                setJQueryAutocompleterURL(jQuery('#mapTypeList_widget'),"your json request", "extraparameter=" + ui.item.value, "the list used in the json", "mapTypeList", "map_type", "/mapNameListChange", "/mapTypeListChange");
            };
        },null);
```

where setJQueryAutocompleterURL is another function

```
function setJQueryAutocompleterURL(widget,href, hrefparameter, list, id, name, selectTopics, listenTopics) {

        var options_auto_iban_widget = {};
        options_auto_iban_widget.hiddenid = "mapTypeList";
        options_auto_iban_widget.selectBox = true;
            options_auto_iban_widget.selectBoxIcon= true;
        options_auto_iban_widget.forceValidOption = true;
        options_auto_iban_widget.onselecttopics = "/autoDebtorIbanChange";
        options_auto_iban_widget.list = list;
        options_auto_iban_widget.listkey = "id";
        options_auto_iban_widget.listvalue = "name";
        options_auto_iban_widget.jqueryaction = "autocompleter";
        options_auto_iban_widget.id = id;
        options_auto_iban_widget.name = name + "_widget";
        options_auto_iban_widget.href = href+"?"+hrefparameter;
        options_auto_iban_widget.listentopics = "/autoDebtorBicChange"; 
        jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(widget,options_auto_iban_widget);
    }
```

Then you will have the extraparameter to get as a param of your json call to filter the result.