# struts2 jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, struts2, autocomplete, struts2-jquery

I have followed the sample of Struts jQuery Autocompleter and the tag with attributes

```
<sj:autocompleter id="destination" name="destination" list="%{locationList}" listValue="name"  listKey="id" selectBox="true" selectBoxIcon="true" 
cssClass="styled-dropdown" onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect"/>
```

and have

```
$.subscribe('autocompleteSelect', function(event,data).
```

My question is after a location is selected, I would like to get the selection key value then query geocode  from db then reload the map marker on the map. I tried to use getElementById on the input tag "destination" which autocompleter generates for me but the value doesn't set yet during the autocompleteSelect event. Is there a way that I can get the "input" tag value during the autocomplete selection?

And I could get the key value using (event.originalEvent.ui.item.option['value']) in the subscribe event, but I don't know how to replace the old map marker with the new one for I have 2 autocomplete tags, one is for startLocation and one is destination.  Is there any way to let event know which element is calling autocompleteSelect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the href of the widget of your second autocompleter to the old json query + an extraparmeter using

```
jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(widget,options_auto_iban_widget);
```

I just post an example on :
[How to reload the struts2-jquery autocompleter X with value selected from another struts2-jquery autocompleter Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608149/how-to-reload-the-struts2-jquery-autocompleter-x-with-value-selected-from-anothe/19301212#19301212)